# Drag and Drop identifying what is being dragged

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have a question with regards to the Drag and Drop API in Chrome.

I have two rectangle divs(#leftpart and #rightpart) and two divs containing the text "Blue" and "Red".

```js
var blue = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[3]

function changeBlue(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 if(e.type == "drop")
 e.target.className = "blue"
}

leftpart.addEventListener("dragover",changeBlue);
leftpart.addEventListener("drop",changeBlue);
```

```css
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #box{
   border:1px solid black;
   width:600px;
   height:400px;
   margin:auto;
   position:relative;
  }

  #leftpart{
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   width:299px;
   height:398px;
   border:1px solid black;
  }

  #rightpart{
   position: absolute;
   right:0;
   width:299px;
   height:398px;
   border:1px solid black;
  }

  .blue{
   background-color : blue;
  }

  .red{
   background-color :red;
  }
  #blue{
   font-size:2em;
   color:blue;
  }
  #red{
   font-size:2em;
   color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box">
 <div id="leftpart"></div>
 <div id="rightpart"></div>
</div>
<div id= "blue">Blue</div>
<div id= "red">Red</div>
```

When I drop the Blue text onto the left box #leftpart , it works fine.But, it also turns blue if I drop the Red text in #leftpart. How can I make sure that the rectangles only correspond to the individual colors (meaning EITHER box turns only the color that is dropped into it.)

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the entirety of your code? It seems like a few things are missing, but they could have just been missed when pasting into the question.

Comment: So... you have to highlight the text "Blue" to drag it? Shouldn't that html element be draggable?

Comment: The text is automatically draggable in chrome and nope this is my entire code, I double checked.

Comment: Well @Whothehellisthat made a good point: I'm using chrome and I still have to highlight. It would be better (standard) to use the html5 attribute, 'draggable' to notify the browser.

Comment: Noted. Any ideas on the actual question anyone?

Comment: @Mozar Sorry, working on one while 'working' lol

Comment: Okay, sorry. I meant to post a follow-up comment to that one. You can use `event.dataTransfer.setData()` to set up some data attached to the currently dragged item. Then in the drop event, you can use `event.dataTransfer.getData()` to get that data out again. So you can set the data to "red" when dragging from the red element, and then use that to decide what colour the drop-zone should be. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

Comment: @Whothehellisthat thanks for the input. I had already considered the dataTransfer set and getData() methods but it doesn't seem to work for me. An illustration would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An illustration for the `setData` and `getData` methods!
Main things to note about this method:

- The draggable element needs to handle the `dragstart` event
- This element needs to set the `dropEffect` and `effectAllowed` properties
- This element, and event, is where the `setData` call must be made.
- The drop destination element needs to handle the `dragover` and `drop` events
- These events must call `getData`; the data will not be available before this event!

**HTML**
Code was modified to include `draggable` attributes, and classes, for simplicity.

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="leftpart" class="dropparts"></div>
    <div id="rightpart" class="dropparts"></div>
</div>
<div id= "blue" class="colordrag" draggable="true">Blue</div>
<div id= "red" class="colordrag" draggable="true">Red</div>
```

**CSS**
A just class additions, to assist with the selecting of draggable items.

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #box{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
  }

  #leftpart{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    width:299px;
    height:398px;
    border:1px solid black;
  }

  #rightpart{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    width:299px;
    height:398px;
    border:1px solid black;
  }

  .blue{
    background-color : blue;
  }

  .red{
    background-color :red;
  }
  #blue{
    color:blue;
  }
  #red{
    color:red;
  }

/* Class for draggable items */
.colordrag {
  /* prevents text highlights */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  font-size: 2em
}
```

**JS**
Still vanilla; Modified code to explain `setData` and `getData`. A little cleaner too.

```
/* Create vars for blue/red divs, and 
 * left/right parts. Also create vars
 * for classes.
 */
var blue = document.getElementById("blue"),
    red = document.getElementById("red"),
    leftpart = document.getElementById("leftpart"),
    rightpart = document.getElementById("rightpart"),
    colordrags = document.getElementsByClassName("colordrag"),
    dropparts = document.getElementsByClassName("dropparts");

/* Create function to handle the drop of
 * one element, onto another.
 * Will take in target element and event.dataTransfer object.
 */
function changeColor(target, ev) {
  document.getElementById(target.id).style.backgroundColor = ev.getData("text");
}

/* Create handlers for colordrag divs to deal
 * with the dragging of elements, and 
 * droppart divs to deal with dropping of
 * elements on them.
 */

for(var i=0; i<colordrags.length; i++) {
  colordrags[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";  // dropEffect and effectAllowed
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all";  // set to enable datatransfer;
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.srcElement.innerHTML); // set data as element text;
    ev.stopPropagation();
  });
}

for(var i=0; i<dropparts.length; i++) {
  dropparts[i].addEventListener("dragover", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  });
  dropparts[i].addEventListener("drop", function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all";
    ev.preventDefault();
    changeColor(ev.target, ev.dataTransfer);
  });
}
```

http://codepen.io/vulpcod3z/full/qNJGGP/